# State returning undefined from Fetch action to Rails backend

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a Rails backend set up (for an array of ingredients), and it was working previously, however now the fetch action in my Dispatch Action Creator function is returning an `undefined` state (not retrieving ingredients).
The API endpoints are working perfectly fine (checked through server), however the fetch action is not retrieving the ingredients, and is returning a `response.json` that is undefined.

I put breakpoints everywhere, to check the state. I have tried to change the contents of the `mapStateToProps` for the component as well, but the state was `undefined` before going into the `mapState` function.

IngredientList component

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { createStructuredSelector } from "reselect";
import { getIngredients, hideIngredients } from "../actions";

class IngredientList extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { ingredients } = this.props;
    const ingredientsList = ingredients.map(ingredient => {
      return (
        <li key={ingredient.id}>
          {ingredient.id}. {ingredient.name}
        </li>
      );
    });

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div>
          <button
            className="button"
            onClick={() => this.props.getIngredients()}
          >
            Get Ingredients
          </button>
          <button
            className="button"
            onClick={() => this.props.hideIngredients()}
          >
            Hide Ingredients
          </button>
        </div>

        <ul>{ingredientsList}</ul>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

const structuredSelector = createStructuredSelector({
  ingredients: state => state.ingredients
});

const mapDispatchToProps = { getIngredients, hideIngredients };

export default connect(
  structuredSelector,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(IngredientList);
```

Actions

```
export function getIngredientsRequest() {
  return {
    type: GET_INGREDIENTS_REQUEST
  };
}

export function getIngredientsSuccess(json) {
  return {
    type: GET_INGREDIENTS_SUCCESS,
    json
  };
}

export function hideIngredients() {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch({ type: HIDE_INGREDIENTS });
  };
}

export function getIngredients() {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(getIngredientsRequest());
    return fetch(`v1/ingredients`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => dispatch(getIngredientsSuccess(json)))
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
  };
}
```

Reducers

```
const initialState = {
  ingredients: []
};

function rootReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  console.log(action.type);
  switch (action.type) {
    case "GET_INGREDIENTS_SUCCESS":
      console.log(action.json);
      return { ...state, ingredients: action.json.ingredients }
    case "GET_INGREDIENTS_REQUEST":
      console.log('Ingredients request received')
      return
    case "HIDE_INGREDIENTS":
      console.log('Ingredients are being hidden')
      return { ...state, ingredients: [] }
    case "GET_INGREDIENT_REQUEST":
      console.log('One Ingredient request received:', "id:", action.id)
      return
    case "GET_INGREDIENT_SUCCESS":
      console.log('GET_INGREDIENT_SUCCESS')
      const ingredients = action.json.ingredients;
      const id = action.id;

      return {
                ...state,
                ingredients: ingredients.filter(ingredient => ingredient.id.toString() === id)
            }
    default:
      return state
  }
}

export default rootReducer;
```

```
GET_INGREDIENTS_REQUEST reducers.js:6 
Ingredients request received reducers.js:12
```

This is in the `structuredSelector` for `IngredientList.js:42`

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ingredients' of undefined

Comment: Could you please add a code snippet about ingredients reducer as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the issue is coming from the reducer below where you are trying to access the `action.json.ingredients` property here:

```
switch (action.type) {
  case "GET_INGREDIENTS_SUCCESS":
    console.log(action.json);
    return { ...state, ingredients: action.json.ingredients } // here
```

In the following code snippet please check how the the response value - variable `json` - is passed to `getIngredientsSuccess` function:

```
export function getIngredients() {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(getIngredientsRequest());
    return fetch(`v1/ingredients`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => dispatch(getIngredientsSuccess(json))) // json value
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
  };
}
```

My assumption is the value is returned like the following from the API endpoint:

```
[
  {id: 12, name: 'test12'},
  {id: 13, name: 'test13'},
]
```

And not like this:

```
{
  ingredients: [
    {id: 12, name: 'test12'},
    {id: 13, name: 'test13'},
  ]
}
```

So to resolve the issue, you might want to change the following line in the reducer:

```
switch (action.type) {
  case "GET_INGREDIENTS_SUCCESS":
    console.log(action.json);
    // removed .ingredients
    // original value: action.json.ingredients 
    return { ...state, ingredients: action.json }
```

I hope this resolves your problem, if not just let me know so we can investigate further.

Additionally it is worth to handle `null` and `undefined` values for your variable before calling `map` function on `ingredients` variable in rendering as below:

```
const { ingredients } = this.props;
const ingredientsList = ingredients != null ? ingredients.map(ingredient => {
  return (
    <li key={ingredient.id}>
      {ingredient.id}. {ingredient.name}
    </li>);
}) : null;
```

***UPDATE:***

Initially your code calls `getIngredientsRequest` function which goes to the following lines of code where the code does not return the state object:

```
case "GET_INGREDIENTS_REQUEST":
  console.log('Ingredients request received')
  return // missing state
```

So I guess the following correction will do the job here and most likely you won't get the error message further:

```
case "GET_INGREDIENTS_REQUEST":
  console.log('Ingredients request received')
  return state;
```

Let me highlight one important thing about reducer's return statement:

> In Redux a reducer takes the starting state and an item to process, and return the new state.

Other important rule is the following:

> Always return the state, even if you didn't change it, and even if it's just null. You may not return undefined.

So the reducer should have the new state in the return statement which in this case it was `undefined` and that caused the error message.

Please read further about reducers here: [Actions and reducers: updating state](https://read.reduxbook.com/markdown/part1/03-updating-state.html).

Comment: I changed the action.json.ingredients to action.json but the same issue happens:
I am getting the json from the "get ingredients success" action from the reducer, here is the console log in the reducer:

```action: {type: "GET_INGREDIENTS_SUCCESS", json: {…}}json: {ingredients: Array(891)}type: "GET_INGREDIENTS_SUCCESS"__proto__: Object action.json.ingredients: (891) [{…},  etc {…},  …]```

However, this information appears AFTER the 

```Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ingredients' of undefined```
in the structuredSelector in IngredientList component.
@norbitrial

Comment: Just updated the answer with my finding, please check it above.

Comment: Glad to help! :)